# Angular - Name with title base on case

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the following data in Angular:

```
data = [
  {"id": "1", "firstname": "Test", "lastname": "Test2", "sex": "Female"},
  {"id": "2", "firstname": "fname", "lastname": "lname", "sex": "Male"},
  {"id": "3", "firstname": "Rajesh", "lastname": "Singh", "sex": "Male"},
  {"id": "4", "firstname": "Sim", "lastname": "Sen", "sex": "Female"}
]
```

I want the output as:

> Mrs. Test Test2
>
> Mr. fname lastname
>
> Mr. Rajesh Singh
>
> Mrs. Sim Sen

My Code:-

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let d of data">
      {{ d.firstname }}  {{d.lastname}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please tell me how can I convert the gender to Mr and Mrs.
I am new to Angular.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plenty of ways you can achieve:

**Solution 1:** Implement the ternary conditional to display title in the view.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let d of data">
      {{ d.sex == 'Male' ? 'Mr.' : d.sex == 'Female' ? 'Mrs.' : '' }} {{ d.firstname }} {{d.lastname}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Solution 2:** Add the `title` properties in each object for the `data` array.

```
this.data = this.data.map((x) => ({
  ...x,
  title: x.sex == 'Male' ? 'Mr.' : x.sex == 'Female' ? 'Mrs.' : '',
}));
```

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let d of data">
      {{ d.title }} {{ d.firstname }} {{d.lastname}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Solution 3:** Implement Angular pipe

You can create an Angular pipe for title by passing the `sex` value. This approach will provide a better performance as Angular pipe will cache the pipe result.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'title'
})
export class TitlePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value == 'Male' ? 'Mr.' : value == 'Female' ? 'Mrs.' : '';
  }
}
```

Make sure that you have imported the pipe into the app module before using it.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let d of data">
      {{ d.sex | title }} {{ d.firstname }} {{d.lastname}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uned6c?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using Angular's interpolation `{{ }}` with a conditional (ternary) operator. This operator can be used to render the correct title based on the gender. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let d of data">
      {{ d.sex === 'Male' ? 'Mr.' : 'Mrs.' }} {{ d.firstname }} {{ d.lastname }}
    </li>
</ul>
```